# How to compute a numeric sentiment score using quanteda from a custom dictionary

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I have been using the AWESOME quanteda library for text analysis lately and it has been quite a joy, recently I have stumbled with a task and that is to use a dictionary relating words to a numeric sentiment score to summarize a measure per document called: NetSentScore which is calculating in the following manner:

NetSentScore per document= sum(Positive_word*score)+sum(Negative_word*score)

I have the following dictionary:

```
ScoreDict<- tibble::tibble(
  score= c(-5,-9,1,8,9,-10),
  word = c("bad", "horrible", "open","awesome","gorgeous","trash")
)
```

My corpus

```
text<-c("this is a bad movie very bad","horrible movie, just awful","im open to new dreams",
         "awesome place i loved it","she is gorgeous","that is trash")
```

by definition quanteda will not allow to have numeric data in a dictionary, but I can have this:

```
> text %>% 
+   corpus() %>% 
+   tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>% 
+   tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
+   dfm() 
Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 14 features (82.14% sparse) and 0 docvars.
       features
docs    bad movie horrible just awful im open new dreams awesome
  text1   2     1        0    0     0  0    0   0      0       0
  text2   0     1        1    1     1  0    0   0      0       0
  text3   0     0        0    0     0  1    1   1      1       0
  text4   0     0        0    0     0  0    0   0      0       1
  text5   0     0        0    0     0  0    0   0      0       0
  text6   0     0        0    0     0  0    0   0      0       0
[ reached max_nfeat ... 4 more features ]
```

which gives me the number or times a word was found in a document, I will only need to "join" or "merge" with my dictionary so I have have the score by each word and then compute the NetSentScore, is there a way to do this in quanteda?

Please keep in mind that I do have a quite massive large corpus so converting my dfm to a dataframe will make the RAM die as I have over 500k documents and approx 800 features.

```
to illustrate the NetSentScore of text1 will be:
2*-5+0=-10, this is because the word bad appears two times and according to the dictionary it has a score of -5
```

Comment: Have you looked into the quanteda.sentiment package?https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.sentiment

Comment: I have but yet again... It does not tell you how to create your own personalized dicctionary with numeric valances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stomper suggests, you can do this with the quanteda.sentiment package, by setting the numeric values as "valences" for the dictionary. Here's how to do it.

This ought to work on 500k documents but of course this will depend on your machine's capacity.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.4
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 70.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
library("quanteda.sentiment")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'quanteda.sentiment'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:quanteda':
#> 
#>     data_dictionary_LSD2015

dict <- dictionary(list(
  sentiment = c("bad", "horrible", "open", "awesome", "gorgeous", "trash")
))

valence(dict) <- list(
  sentiment = c(bad = -5, 
                horrible = -9, 
                open = 1, 
                awesome = 8, gorgeous = 9, 
                trash = -10)
)

print(dict)
#> Dictionary object with 1 key entry.
#> Valences set for keys: sentiment 
#> - [sentiment]:
#>   - bad, horrible, open, awesome, gorgeous, trash

text <- c("this is a bad movie very bad",
          "horrible movie, just awful",
          "im open to new dreams",
          "awesome place i loved it",
          "she is gorgeous",
          "that is trash")
```

Now to compute the document scores, you use `textstat_valence()` but you sent the normalisation to "none" in order to sum the valences rather than average them.  Normalisation is the default because raw sums are affected by documents having different lengths, but as this package is still in a developmental stage, it's easy to imagine that other choices might be preferable to the default.

```r
textstat_valence(tokens(text), dictionary = dict, normalization = "none")
#>   doc_id sentiment
#> 1  text1       -10
#> 2  text2        -9
#> 3  text3         1
#> 4  text4         8
#> 5  text5         9
#> 6  text6       -10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I KNEW there was a way!!!!!!!!! This package may be in a developmental stage but it is STRONGGGG AND POWERFUL omg! thank you so much professor Ken!